# Can Emacs js2-mode be forced into not indenting top-level JS when the file is wrapped in a module function?

Tags: javascript, emacs, js2-mode

A lot of JS code I work with contains files that are defined with the following indentation:

```
define("my_module", function() {

// top-level code is not indented because the whole file
// is wrapped in a giant closure

});
```

Is there a way to force Emacs (js2-mode) to ignore the outer function for the purposes of indentation (such that it indents the same as if it was not wrapped in a giant function)?

Comment: This is not an answer, but here's what I do: since I'll minify the code anyway, I just have the same script that minifies it also wrap it into whatever module/wrapper function I need. This also has the effect of having working outlines for functions.

Comment: Same question but more generally: not indenting top-level items wrapped in an IIFE.